How to skip a TestCaseFilter when running dotnet test?
When running dotnet test, I'm trying to skip integration tests. To achieve this, I added the following to my .csproj file:
<RunSettingsFilePath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\test.runsettings</RunSettingsFilePath>

I also created a test.runsettings file with the following content:
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <TestCaseFilter>(TestKind!=Integration)</TestCaseFilter>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>

In my test class, I added the [Trait("TestKind", "Integration")] attribute
This setup works fine. However, I now want to run only the integration tests from the command line using:
dotnet test --filter "TestKind=Integration"

But this doesn't seem to work because the testcase filter is applied. Is there a way to ignore the testcase filter?
I can overwrite the specified .runsettings file with "dotnet test --settings path-to-runsettings-file-without-testcase-filter". This works, but I want a solution where I don't have to create an additional .runsettings file.
